# Check MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am a paranoid kind of guy and even though I included `mysql_close()` in my PHP functions after I do something, is there a way I can check (besides another query) to see if the connection is still open, just for assurance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mysql_close()` function returns `true` if it succeeded.  By adding an extra check outside of checking the return value of `mysql_close()`, you aren't doing anything helpful, and adding another place bugs can crop up in your code.

In any case, non-persistent connections are closed automatically when your script finishes, so it isn't necessary, unless you have some specific reason to kill off the resource ahead of time.

Comment: That works. Do I need to request a connection every time I make a query then and if so, do I need to close it at the end of the script? What you're saying here is once 'function connectAndMakeSomeQuery()' has run its course, the connection will close?

Comment: No, use one connection for all of your queries.  You do not need to (and should not) close and re-open it again for each query.  You also shouldn't combine your connection and query code in one function, for the same reason.  Connect once, and re-use that connection for all queries.  Once your script is finished (not function, but entire program), then MySQL will be disconnected automatically as PHP cleans up resources.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [**mysql_ping()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php)

Here is an excerpt from that page:

```
bool mysql_ping ([ resource $link_identifier ] )
Checks whether or not the connection to the server is working.
If it  has gone down, an automatic reconnection is attempted.
This function can be used by scripts that remain idle for a long while,
to check whether or not the server has closed the connection and
reconnect if necessary. 

Note:  Since MySQL 5.0.13, automatic reconnection feature is disabled.
```

As for this excerpt, I do not know whether the *automatic reconnection feature is disabled* comment refers to mysql or PHP. You will have to experiment with it to find out. If this reconnection issue is indeed true, then @Brad's answer is paranoid-proof since you could run mysql_close immediately after querying the data and fetching it. You can be sure at that point that there is no valid connection since you explicitly closed it. Consequently, you would have to run mysql_connect for your next query.

However, letting non-persistent connections close on there own is not always a good idea because this could potentially stockpile TIME_WAITs in the DB Server's netstat. This would fool webservers into thinking that DB Connections are no longer available because MySQL ran out where the OS would actually be the cause since it would delay releasing Connection Resources. To be better safe that sorry, run mysql_close when done and mysql_connect/mysql_query for the next query.

If you are willing, you could construct a try-catch paradigm or a set of if-then-else stataments to first run mysql_ping on an established connection. If true, use it with mysql_query. Otherwise, run mysql_close/mysql_connect/mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"name", "pass");
/* your code*/

if ($con){
   mysql_close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if you open mysql connection with mysql_pconnect(), they don't really clossed after mysql_close(), it's just return to connection pool